# How to display a 2D list in this form?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

How i can convert 2d list like this?

```
lista=[[1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 5],[8, 5, 9]]  to 
listb=[[1 2 3]
       [3 4 5]
       [8 5 9]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out, what you have is already basically the same representation of one list in Python, so a list to list conversion doesn't make much sense. However, if you want a list to string conversion - ways to output the list as a nice string, you have the option of [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html), or pretty-printing. This is a module from the standard library that seems pretty close to what you're looking for:

```
import pprint

l = [[1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 5],[8, 5, 9]]

pprint.pprint(l, width=12)
```

Gives the output

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [8, 5, 9]]
```

Now I've had to artificially reduce its maximum width a bit as your lists are so short that `pprint`, by default, does not consider them worth shortening.

Also, if you want the string representation in your program, you can use `pprint.pformat` in pretty much the same way, except it returns a string:

```
import pprint

l = [[1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 5],[8, 5, 9]]

s = pprint.pformat(l, width=12)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume what you're looking for is the `__repr__` of a list - how it is displayed. Semantically, the two are one and the same.

However, if you want to display your lists like that, this is how you might do it.

1. The simple way with `numpy`:

   ```
   import numpy as np

   lst = [[1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 5],[8, 5, 9]]
   print(np.array(lst))

   [[1 2 3]
    [3 4 5]
    [8 5 9]]
   ```
2. The grotesque way, using vanilla python.

   ```
   print('[' + '\n '.join(str(x).replace(',', '') for x in lst) + ']')
   [[1 2 3]
    [3 4 5]
    [8 5 9]]
   ```
3. The other answer mentions `pprint.pprint` which I consider a simpler alternative to 2, but limited flexibility. You could instead use `pprint.pformat` to prettify your list and get rid of commas:

   ```
   import pprint
   print(pprint.pformat(lista, width=12).replace(',', ''))

   [[1 2 3]
    [3 4 5]
    [8 5 9]]
   ```

Comment: Nice use of pformat. If you don't want any commas, I'd say that's the way to go.